# jQuery Drop event is not working

Tags: jquery, droppable

I facing a weird problem here. I already have a simple try-out for jquery drag-n-drop and it WORKS. However, now i wan to move the code from the try-out project to the project file i working right now. Everything is the SAME, but i just cant get the drop event to be fired. It is really urgent, please help...
I included my code, just in case...

```
  $('.image').draggable({
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        // Put img resizable is to have the ghost
        $('.image img').resizable({
            ghost: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var eid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                alert(eid);
                var wid = $(this).width();
                alert(wid);
                var hei = $(this).height();
                alert(hei);
                updateSize(eid, wid, hei);
            }
        });

        // Variable to hold drop options
        var options = {};

        // Once image re-drop, update its position
        options.drop = function (event, ui) {
            // Check image id to check whether image exist or not
            if (ui.draggable.attr('id').match(/_(\d+)$/) != null) {
                var element = ui.draggable;
                updatePosition(element);
            }
            else {

                // Store the clone position
                var leftPosition = ui.offset.left;
                var topPosition = ui.offset.top;
                alert('Left: ' + leftPosition + ' Top: ' + topPosition);

                // Variable to generate new image id
                var counter = new Date().valueOf();

                // Create the clone
                //var element = ui.draggable.clone();

                // Assign new id for clone element
                var oldID = ui.draggable.attr('id');
                alert('old id ' + oldID);
                ui.draggable.attr('id', (oldID + '_' + counter));

                // Call CreateContainer
                createContainer(ui.draggable, oldID, topPosition, leftPosition);
            }
        };
        $('#rightframe').droppable(options);
```

Comment: have you included jquery.js and jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/DrUKa/